# ActionController::UnknownFormat error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

Please excuse me, I am new to Ruby and Rails.

I am running a rails server. 
When I go to localhost:3000, everything is fine.
When I navigate to the page that I am testing, everything is still fine.
When I select a video to upload and then click submit I get the following run-time error:

ActionController::UnknownFormat in xyzController#create

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @v_res.save
        ...
```

The code works on other computers, namely Macs. I am running Windows. Could this be an OS or browser issue?

Comment: What is your `create` action code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Very simple things. I was uploading the wrong type of file for a particular parameter. After that, I was getting another type of error which I resolved by disabling AdBlockPlus and NoScript.

Comment: AdBlockPlus is usually fine; NoScript kills lots of pages that cannot live without js